# Can we call HTTP method from JSON Column formatting in sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, json-formatting, column-formatting

I want to update/change the status column value through HTTP Request(HTTP method that will call flow).

Do JSON column formatting support this HTTP method?

Answer (score 0):

We can have HTTP call, only to get the schema file. Apart from that no other calls allowed. In JSON column formatting, we are just creating JSON object, that describes the elements that are displayed when a field is included in a list view, and the styles to be applied to those elements.

Both column formatting and [SharePoint Framework Field Customizer extensions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-simple-field-customizer) enable you to customize how fields in SharePoint lists are displayed. The Field Customizer is more powerful because you can use it to write any code that you want to control how a field is displayed.

Column formatting is more easily and broadly applied. However, it is less flexible, because it does not allow for custom code; it only allows for certain predefined elements and attributes.

Answer (score 0):

JSON Formatting does not support any HTTP Calls directly.

But, In JSON Formatting you can **create a button to launch a Flow**.

And in Microsoft flow/Power Automate, you can call use **Send an HTTP request to SharePoint** action.

**OR** You can use **Update item** action as you want update only Status column.

> You can use column formatting to create buttons that, when selected, run Flows on the corresponding list item. The Flow Launch Panel will be displayed after choosing the button and the Flow will just run.
>
> To use the sample below, you must substitute the ID of the Flow you want to run. This ID is contained within the customRowAction attribute inside the button element. To obtain a Flow's ID:
>
> 1. Choose Flow > See your flows in the SharePoint list where the Flow is configured.
> 2. Choose the Flow you want to run.
> 3. Copy the ID from the end of the URL.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "button",
  "customRowAction": {
    "action": "executeFlow",
    "actionParams": "{\"id\": \"edf627d9-20f4-45ba-8bc9-4494bf2ff1be\"}"
  },
  "attributes": {
    "class": "ms-fontColor-themePrimary ms-fontColor-themeDarker--hover"
  },
  "style": {
    "border": "none",
    "background-color": "transparent",
    "cursor": "pointer"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "attributes": {
        "iconName": "Flow"
      },
      "style": {
        "padding-right": "6px"
      }
    },
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "txtContent": "Send to Manager"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Source**: [Create a button to launch a Flow](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#create-a-button-to-launch-a-flow).

**References**:

1. [How can I update only 1 property in a SharePoint List?](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/How-can-I-update-only-1-property-in-a-SharePoint-List/td-p/82047)
2. [Send an HTTP request to Sharepoint to Update List Items](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Send-an-HTTP-request-to-Sharepoint-to-Update-List-Items/td-p/153606).

Comment: Hi Deepak, have you tried this? Is it working for you?